# ¿Cómo se agregan índices en Firebase con Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, indices

¡Hola!
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil, donde uso Firebase. Sin embargo, me gustaría agregar índices ya que tengo un solo listado colaborativo compartido entre los diferentes usuarios. Por esta razón me gustaría saber cómo puedo crear índices a través del uso de la función push()  para que genere un identificador único para cada elemento guardado de tal forma que múltiples usuarios puedan escribir al mismo tiempo y no haya ningún conflicto.

Gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `push()` funciona creando un valor único garantizado por Firebase y los inserta en el nodo en el que se lo llama el resultado de `push()` es una nueva referencia al nodo que corresponde a es ID único. por ejemplo:

```
//obtengo el nodo que contiene la info de usuarios    
DatabaseReference usuarios = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usuarios");

//Esto crea un nuevo nodo con UUID (único)
DatabaseReference nuevoUsuario = usuarios.push();

//desde acá pueden usar la referencia nuevoUsuario para setear los valores
```